# Recover Data from Deleted RBD Volume?

Tags: ceph, data-recovery

Is there any way to recover data from deleted RBD volume in Ceph? thanks

```
$ ceph osd map pool-name csi-vol-65c11863-32e1-11eb-a202-cab20b4e04f6
osdmap e2248 pool 'pool-name' (8) object 'csi-vol-65c11863-32e1-11eb-a202-cab20b4e04f6' -> pg 8.e5d09b91 (8.11) -> up ([5,4], p5) acting ([5,4], p5)
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the kubernetes workflow but there's a `rbd trash`, maybe that volume is still in the trash? `rbd -p <pool> trash ls`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, the answer is No. However, I am citing a following explanation from the [source](https://ceph-users.ceph.narkive.com/8jZ1V0Bn/recover-data-from-deleted-rbd-volume) that may be helpful for you:

> Consider the way Ceph stores data... each RBD is striped into chunks
> (RADOS objects with 4MB size by default); the chunks are distributed
> among the OSDs with the configured number of replicates (probably two in
> your case since you use 2 OSD hosts). RBD uses thin provisioning, so
> chunks are allocated upon first write access.
> If an RBD is deleted all of its chunks are deleted on the corresponding
> OSDs. If you want to recover a deleted RBD, you need to recover all
> individual chunks. Whether this is possible depends on your filesystem
> and whether the space of a former chunk is already assigned to other
> RADOS objects. The RADOS object names are composed of the RBD name and
> the offset position of the chunk, so if an undelete mechanism exists for
> the OSDs' filesystem, you have to be able to recover file by their
> filename, otherwise you might end up mixing the content of various
> deleted RBDs. Due to the thin provisioning there might be some chunks
> missing (e.g. never allocated before).

However, there is still some hope. The Ceph book called **Mastering Ceph** has given some [hints](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/virtualization_and_cloud/9781789610703/12/ch12lvl1sec89/rbd-recovery) to recover the data as following:

> there are tools that can search through the OSD data structure, find the object files relating to RBDs, and then assemble these objects back into a disk image, resembling the original RBD image.

May be you need to find the right tool in Ceph source code.